# Where can I get metrics data on one retail store, for 3 - 4 years time?

Tags: data-request, finance

Where can I get metrics data on one retail store, for 3 - 4 years time? I need data such as sales per day, conversion, number of transactions, number of units, etc. 
Granular data per hour or per sales person, even better. Conversion/traffic is an absolute must. It could be data for one store, but data on multiple stores, same company, even better.
I can use an API or scrape if needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not likely that this data set would be open, but you can use pseudo-data, for example the [Superstore example from Tableau](https://community.tableau.com/thread/143519) (there is an downloadable Excel file in the page).

[image]

---

If you're flexible with the data-request, then I would suggest thinking of "retail-like" stores that may satisfy your need. For example, would a national park or museum work? For public or government entities, it's easier to find open data.

Comment: This is a great suggestion, thanks. Maybe they will have data on their gift shops. I think I do need real data, I am not sure pseudo will do...